# Issue with prerender.io always rendering the default angular route for a list of client side routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, seo, prerender

Just want to say I really like prerender.io, but I am currently having an issue with it and I am wondering if maybe I am doing something wrong and people with more experience with the service can help me out.

I am having the same issue with the prerender.io site and also with a Debian Linux box I setup with prerender for local execution.

My new site is a hybrid of ASP.Net MVC and angular, where angular represents workflows (or categories of content) within MVC routes on the server.

An example of a category of content is this:

```
http://[somesitename]/PublicContent/#!/news

http://[somesitename]/PublicContent/#!/welcome
```

The MVC server side route is:

```
http://[somesitename]/PublicContent
```

and **#!/news** and **#!/welcome** are the angular app routes **and welcome is also the default route**.

When I send my URL to the prerender.io service or my local instance:

```
http://service.prerender.io/http://[somesitename]/PublicContent/#!/news
```

The prerender service is only ever rendering:

```
http://[somesitename]/PublicContent
```

and is ignoring the client side route after the #!

so for all my pages for each MVC route I am merely getting the default route rendered multiple times...

Is this a bug with prerender.io? Or do I not have something not properly configurered?

I do have the:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

in the head for all my pages if that would matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talked with the guys over at prerender.io, and it appears that a modification I made to the Asp.Net MVC middleware where it was removing **?_escpaed_fragment_=/** completely was an incorrect modification to this code, which itself was incorrect (the base code removed **?_escpaed_fragment_=/** and replaced it with nothing, I modified the code to remove **?_escpaed_fragment_=/** and replace it with **#!**).

The prerender.io service expected **?_escpaed_fragment_=/** to exist in the URL and if it finds it it will replace it with **#!** before calling your website to cache the page. It doesn't expect to find the **#!**, so it won't properly process the URL if it is there.

So if you are using the Asp.Net MVC middleware you should comment out the following code from **PrerenderModule.cs**:

```
        // Remove the _escaped_fragment_ from the URL if it exists!
        var escapedFull = "?" + _Escaped_Fragment + "=/";
        if (url.Contains(escapedFull))
        {
            url = url.Replace(escapedFull, string.Empty);
        }
```